# C++ var in class does not name a type

Tags: c++, arduino

I know this question has been asked many times but none of the answers I found have been able to help me. I am trying to build a `std::vector` and fill it in with `structs`. I want to make these variables static and constant, so they can be passed around easily. My code right now is:

Melodies.h

```
#ifndef Melodies_h
#define Melodies_h

#include "Arduino.h"
#include <StandardCplusplus.h>
#include <vector>

struct Note {
  int note;
  int duration;

  Note(int a, int b) : note(a), duration(b) {}
};

struct Melody {
  std::vector<Note> notes;

  void addNote(Note note) {
    notes.push_back(note);
  }
};

const Melody NONE;
const Melody BILL;
const Melody COIN;
// this gives an error
//COIN.addNote(Note(NOTE_C4, 5));

#endif
```

Melodies.cpp

```
#include "Melodies.h"
#include "Notes.h"

// this gives an error
//COIN.addNote(Note(NOTE_C4, 5));
```

I get the error(s):

> error: 'COIN' does not name a type

How can I store this type of variable and set it 1 time like I want to do in the `begin` function? I am not using standard c++ - this is on an Arduino using the StandardCplusplus library.

Comment: [Works on gcc](http://ideone.com/JYSP1S)

Comment: [MCVE] please. Anyways, you should do a simple initialization, not using any `begin` function and your design is rather strange.

Comment: Ok, this is on an Arduino using the StandardCplusplus library as I mentioned. If this works fine with standard gcc then it must be the library. I will try to make it much simpler then for Arduino

Comment: I don't think this is a library issue.  I think it's a compiler library.  We really do need that [mcve].  (Try and make the sample smaller than you have shown.  `Note` doesn't need a constructor; we only need to see one static; you probably don't need begin() (the error there is almost certainly consequential); etc.  The aim is not to have a useful program, the aim is to have the simplest program which shows the problem.

Comment: I've tried to create arduino library (Arduino.cc IDE 1.6.9) and it's builded without issues.

Comment: I updated the example to be smaller. Really the idea is to build a `const` that is a `Melody` so I can pass that variable to another class when I need to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated version can't work in this way - you can't change const class and definitely not outside of any function.

However something like this works (arduino.cc Arduino IDE 1.6.9):

*libraries/Melodies/Melodies.h:*

```
#ifndef Melodies_h
#define Melodies_h

#include "Arduino.h"
#include <StandardCplusplus.h>
#include <vector>

struct Note {
  int note;
  int duration;

  Note(int a, int b) : note(a), duration(b) {}
};

using Melody = std::vector<Note>;

extern const Melody NONE;
extern const Melody BILL;
extern const Melody COIN;

#endif
```

*libraries/Melodies/Melodies.cpp:*

```
#include "Melodies.h"
#include "Notes.h"

const Melody NONE;
const Melody BILL;
const Melody COIN = {{NOTE_C4,20},{NOTE_E2,10}}; // whatever
```

*melodies_sketch/melodies_sketch.ino*

```
#include <Melodies.h>

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(57600);

}

void loop() {
  Serial.println(COIN.size()); // just print size of Melodies vector
  delay(1000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you declare object as `const`, you can modify its member values only on initialization. If you could use your `addNote()` anywhere in the program then the `COIN` object wouldn't be constant, would it?

Error you get seems confusing, but try to make COIN non-const, or add a constructor, that will allow you to populate notes vector at initialization.